# Book Recommendation (Financial Mathematics and Itô Calculus)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation

I have learnt the basics about distributions and random variables. Now, I would like to know more, in particular what can be applied to financial mathematics. I have seen that Itô Calculus is crucial, then I searched about it on web pages, however I cannot understand much.

Do you recommend any book, paper e on this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitive Book for the Overview:
- Stochastic Differential Equations - B. Oksendal

Standard Book with all important Concepts:
- Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations - P. Protter

Very rigorous Book as a foundation:
- Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus - Karatzas and Shreve

Comment: Thanks for these recommendations

Comment: You are welcome